Progress on Gromov's Conjecture of the bound of total Betti numbers
This question is a reference request.
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$, and $b_i(M) = \dim H_i(M,\mathbb{R})$. Gromov proved it that there are constants $C(n)$ such that, if the sectional curvature of $M$ is non-negative then $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} b_i(M) \le C(n)$. Reference is here.
Moreover, it was conjectured that the constant can be chosen to be $C(n) = 2^n$. As far as I know the conjecture is true for $n\le 3$. But I wish to know more progress about this conjecture. For example, is there any work about the case when M is a globally symmetric space?
Thanks for any help!

The $2^n$ bound is true for all rationally elliptic spaces, which (I think) includes all known closed simply-connected nonnegatively curved manifolds. Simply-connected symmetric (or more generally, homogeneous) spaces are standard examples of rationally elliptic spaces.
A famous Bott conjecture says that every simply-connected nonnegatively curved manifold is rationally elliptic.
I am not ready to summarize the state-of-the-art on Bott conjecture here, but e.g. see Almost non-negative curvature and rational ellipticity in cohomogeneity two by Grove, Wilking and Yeager for some recent work.
EDIT: let me also explain that the simply-connectedness assumption is irrelevant in the above discussion. Any closed nonnegatively curved manifold $M$ has a finite cover of the form $C\times T$ where $C$ is a simply-connected nonnegatively curved manifold and $T$ is a torus. Betti numbers cannot decrease when we pass to finite covers so using Kunneth formula we get
$$\sum_{i} b_i(M)\le 
\sum_{i} b_i(C\times T^k)=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}b_j(C)b_{i-j}(T)=
\sum_{i} b_i(C)\sum_{j} b_j(T).$$
The conjectural $2^k$ upper bound is attained for the $k$-torus. Thus it is enough to prove the $2^n$ bound in the simply-connected case.

Hi, can you post a reference for a non-negatively curved manifold has a splitting covering like this? Thanks!

This is proved in [Theorem 9.2, On the Structure of Complete Manifolds of Nonnegative Curvature, Cheeger, Gromoll, Annals of Math, 1972]. A detailed exposition can be found e.g. in section 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001125.
